# MySQL Convert STR_TO_DATE with 10 digit microsecond

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I want to convert this string to `datetime` format
`09-OCT-17 03.08.25.907000000 PM`

Unfortunately, this microsecond part is giving a problem for me. It has 9 precision. (edited)

```
select STR_TO_DATE('09-OCT-17 03.08.25 PM', '%d-%b-%y %h.%i.%s %p') as DATE
```

It worked without the microsecond part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not support nano-second precision.  It does support microsecond precision.  If your string always has `000` for the nanosecond portion, you can use:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('09-OCT-17 03.08.25.907000000 PM', '%d-%b-%y %h.%i.%s.%f000 %p')
```

Another option is to munge the string, if these are not always `0`s:

```
select STR_TO_DATE(INSERT('09-OCT-17 03.08.25.907000123 PM', 26, 3, ''), '%d-%b-%y %h.%i.%s.%f %p')
```